# Drools with Struts

Tags: java, struts2, drools

We want to integrate DROOLS with my current web Application which is based on struts 2. Is there a sample Application which could be used as reference?
Generally we are seeing all application use Spring+ Drools.
Also later on can it be possible to integrate Guvnor for a GUI of the rules created?

Comment: I think you need to elaborate on your requirements a little bit more because drools can be used with any java framework or without one in a simple console app for that matter.

Comment: I have a working project in Struts+Hibernate. It is specific to Telecom domain. Now the rules which are applied are being picked from DB or they are static. I want the business rules to be fetched from DROOL. SO my main question is

Comment: SO my main question is a)What all jars are needed. b)What all Configuration changes are to be done. c) How can i create rules which would be relevant to my application using Guvonor if possible as it is very handy.

Comment: Drools should just be another properly encapsulated layer in your application. How you integrate it with Struts is fairly easy: a wrapper layer that exposes the functionality you want in away that keeps the HOW hidden from the WHAT. As to the jars, you need all those required for Drools, Struts 2 and Hibernate. Each project will tell you those needs. As to configuration, again this is all hidden in your rules wrapper. Struts/Hibernate won't need to know. Just follow the Drools tutorial, http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbpm/45-jboss-drools-1.html

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible. Drools is not tier specific, you can plug it into you Java application however you see fit. As a general rule you would incorporate it into your service tier, where all the heavy lifting is done.

Drools needs very little configuration (in many scenarios it needs none at all). Simply drop the applicable JAR files into your library folder and reference them in your classpath.

I actually built a prototype application for a client using Yahoo UI, Struts and Drools. It works like a charm (can't share the source unfortunately). To wit, you are definitely not tied to Spring.

---

As far as your second question, note that using Guvnor to manage rules and accessing those rules from your app logic are two totally separate things. The Guvnor governance application is bundled as a web app that you deploy on a server. Once deployed it provides a very nice interface that you can use for managing a rules repository. To use those managed rules in your application you need to include the appropriate JAR files in your application and do some configuration.

I would recommend standing up a simple application first that simple executes some rules in an embedded DRL, before attempting anything more complex like integrating with Guvnor.

Comment: Hi, I would like to integrate the Drools with Jersey Rest API. I have posted a question- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151071/how-to-integrate-drools-in-jersey-rest-web-service?noredirect=1#comment28327654_19151071
Please help. How to do it in step by step....Thanks for your help.