# How to integrate drools in jersey rest web service

Tags: java, rest, jersey, integration, drools

I have developed a jersey est web service API. Now I would like to integrate DROOLS rules in this rest service. IN the rest service, after ascertaining all required conditions, i would like to send it to the drools rule engine and the fire the rule. How to do this. Please help me step by step guidance.

Comment: You should refer drools tutorial.

Comment: I tried my best but not getting any start-up idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not Jersey, but here is an example of a REST web service, which evaluates requests using Drools:
https://github.com/gratiartis/sctrcd-payment-validation-web

Essentially you create a singleton bean, which wraps the knowledge base. When validation requests arrive, you can create knowledge sessions, insert your facts and execute the rules.

It's built with Spring, so the main change you would need to make if not using Spring would be to ensure that the knowledge base is only created once.

Comment: Thanks for your very great help. I also tried earlier but unable to get the result expected. I downloaded your project. I will also go through this. Could you please create a sample project with jersey rest  API and include with drools with all jars required.